# Is it possible to delete contents of a directory mounted inside itself?

Tags: arch-linux, mount, rm, recursive, root-filesystem

Just for curiosity, is it possible to delete contents in a directory which is mounted inside of itself *OR* in a folder inside it?

For example, I was taking a backup of my Arch installation with Timeshift. I saw that Timeshift mounts `/` at `/run/timeshift/backup/` temporarily. In this case, can I delete contents in my `/` mounted in this mount point? Or, will it  not allow me to delete it's contents recursively?

Comment: How can you mount a directory inside itself? Give an example. Not everybody is running arch and timeshift.

Comment: @user414777 bind mount

Comment: You question is unclear: I have at least two interpretations. e.g. Are you considering removing the directory or the content?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor believing that in `mkdir -p a/b; mount --bind a a/b` the dir `a` is mounted "inside itself" is inaccurate and may be the exact cause of the OP's confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried what you described on Debian inside my user directory. Made a directory `test` and another directory inside it `test/mnt`. Then added some `test/content`. And mounted `test` to `test/mnt` like this:

```
$ sudo mount --bind /home/user/test/ /home/user/test/mnt/
```

Now, if I delete it like this:

```
$ rm -r test/*
```

Or like this:

```
$ rm -r test/mnt/*
```

I get all the content deleted, but the /home/user/test/mnt/ is not deleted because it is busy. Issuing the command under root has the same result.

So, it will allow you to delete the contents, except the mount point itself, unless it runs into another error before that.

Comment: Thanks to all....! I was confused due to some misunderstood terminology. I updated the question accordingly. My doubt is cleared.

Answer (score 0):

deleting /* recursively is not a very good idea.

this is / the root partition that holds all of your os.

it will allow you to delete its content, but you will be surprised at the next boot, as your machine will certainly not boot in any way.